# Problems accessing element style attribute with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css

I am trying to access the style attribute of a element in order to display a form however, I get this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined**.  The example below is a simplified example.

cookies.php

```
echo "[a href='test.php?flavor=butter']Bake Butter Cookies[/a]";

echo "[a href='test.php?flavor=chocolate'] Bake Chocolate Cookies [/a]";
```

?>

test.php

```
switch($cookieType){
 case "chocolate":
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "document.chocolate.style.display='block'; ";
  echo "</script>";
 break;
 case "oatmeal-raisin":
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "document.oatmealraisin.style.display='block'; ";
  echo "</script>";
 break;
 case "butter":
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "document.butter.style.display='block'; ";
  echo "</script>";
 break;
 }
?>

<div id="chocolate" style="display:none;">
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['php_self']?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="chocolate"/>
  What is your name: <input type="text" name="your_name"/>
  How many chocolate chips on each cookie? <input type="text" name="chips"/>
  How many many cookies? <input type="text" name="cookies"/>
  <input type="submit" name="BAKE!"/>
  <input type="reset"/>
 </form>
</div>

 <div id="oatmealraisin" style="display:none;">
 <input type="hidden" name="type" value="oatmealraisin"/>
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['php_self']?>">
  What is your name: <input type="text" name="your_name"/>
  How many raisins on each cookie? <input type="text" name="raisins"/>
  How many many cookies? <input type="text" name="cookies"/>
  <input type="submit" name="BAKE!"/>
  <input type="reset"/>
 </form>
</div>

<div id="butter" style="display:none;">

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['php_self']?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="butter"/>
  What is your name: <input type="text" name="your_name"/>
  How many many cookies? <input type="text" name="cookies"/>
  <input type="submit" name="BAKE!"/>
  <input type="reset"/>
 </form>
```

I have never had problems accessing the style attribute of a element before so I am not sure what is the problem.  The switch statement does work because the javascript console shows the output of the right case.  I need another pair of eyes.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Jeez, maybe it'd be a good idea to **format your code**?

Comment: It would help us help you if you could use the button that looks like a square of binary at the top of the editor to make sure that your code dislays properly. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the style attribute that is the problem, you failed to access the elements themselves.

You are trying to access the elements as if they are global variables in the document object, that is only true in IE in quirks mode. You need to use the getElementById method. Replace:

```
document.chocolate
```

with:

```
document.getElementById('chocolate')
```

and corresponding for each element.

Comment: I fixed the problem by pushing the switch statement at the end of the html.  Thanks for your help.